# Algorithm behind distance calculations in The Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: algorithm, api, routes, distance

How does the Google Distance Matrix API calculate the distance from point A to B. Often there are multiple ways to go from A to B and the question is how Google prioritizes different routes to find the one that is used for the distance calculation. Strategies could be:

1. Fastest
2. Shortest
3. Low risk of queues
4. Etc.

Sincerely,
Henning

Comment: It's probably a shortest-path calculation regardless, with different priorities reflected in lengths of road segments that differ from their actual values. The shortest-path computation itself likely uses hierarchical graph separators or one of the algorithms that exploits low highway dimension.

Comment: They uses fastet travel path.

Comment: Just what I'm after. The API documentation says nothing about the algorithms. An idea of priorities would be great, but I think we also deserve some description of the benchmarks/assumptions used for road speed estimation etc, especially for journey time data.

Answer (score 0):

Google map calculation  uses a fastest calculation but the distance  matrix api can also gives accurate distance in meters. Here is some answer from Nick Johnson unfortunatelynot  about the question: [What algorithms compute directions from point A to point B on a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map). At least the algorithm is a modified. I think with fastest calculation the map is more flexible. I don't see why they can't switch between both?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I don't see how the algorithm can be based on both fastest and shortest, unless choosing between equivalent duration journeys/segments.

Comment: The algorithm  works with time but the distance api also provides distance matrix. with both I don't mean it uses both.  Maybe it not useful that you know? But the title says distance   matrix.

Comment: Its helpful but I think this thread really needs some official referencing.

Comment: Fastest route makes some more sense. Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link to an interesting discussion. Just like @geotheory, I am also looking for facts and references to documentation stating what the strategy is.

Comment: dijkstra algorithm. good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256309/calculate-the-shortest-route/39256428#39256428