# Route optimization by address and by Lat/long

Tags: algorithm, routes, mapping

I just try understand if there any free (open-sourse) code /api where you can give list of coordinates, give them start/end destination get in response route optimized

I find: 
https://graphhopper.com/#directions-api
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5330/route-optimisation-for-multiple-vehicles

[What algorithms compute directions from point A to point B on a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map)

the last one was interesting to read - but still looking for if any solution open to get from GitHub and use it?

Comment: Are you looking for something that will get you from A to B, or something that, given starting point A, will compute optimum route to visit points B, C, and D in any order? If the first, why not use the Google Maps API or one of the [free alternatives](http://www.fubra.com/blog/2011/11/24/google-maps-free-alternatives/)?

Comment: I looking for service (or code) - that I can him My points (A,B,C,D,E,....Z)
I choose B like start point - and J like end point - and i want to get sorted list - what is best (shortest/cheapest) route

Comment: You do realize that you're asking for a solution to the [Traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Yep - and my question is if any open source solution available today?

Comment: The solution to the TSP is known. But the only way to get a provably optimum solution is exhaustive search. For even 26 points, that's a very expensive proposition. It would require getting the travel times between each pair of points (all (n^2)/2 of them), and then running the TSP algorithm, which will take significant time. It's unlikely you'll find a service to do that for you.

Comment: And + I need to know road direction to each one - becuase if A closer then B but on A street is One way - so better go to b - then to a and then to z , right?